# Dropdown value reset to first value while satisfying condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

In the below code, if the current drop-down value points to the value available in *listvalues* variable, then the drop-down selected value should be changed into first value.

```
   if (selectedForYear() == 2016) {
         var d = new Date();
         var month = d.getMonth();
         month = month + 3;
         while (month <= 13) {
             $('#dk_container_selectForMonth .dk_options li:nth-child(' + month + ')').css({ "display": 'none' });
             var listvalues = $('#dk_container_selectForMonth .dk_options li:nth-child(' + month + ')').text();
             if ($('#dk_container_selectForMonth .dk_options li.dk_option_current a').text() == listvalues) 
            {

                 $("#dk_container_selectForMonth").val($("#dk_container_selectForMonth li:first").val());

              }
             month++;
         }
     }
```

I have tried this:

```
$("#dk_container_selectForMonth").val($("#dk_container_selectForMonth li:first").val());
```

but it does not work.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="flexContainer mediumGutter">

    <div class="flexContent">
        <select data-bind="options: month, optionsCaption: 'Month', value: selectedForMonth" id="selectForMonth" tabindex="8" style="width: 130px">
            <option>month</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="flexContent">
        <select data-bind="options: year, optionsCaption: 'Year', value: selectedForYear" id="selectForYear" tabindex="9" style="width: 130px">
            <option>year</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please add the `HTML` as well so that a working snippet can be made. It is hard to debug what you have presented here.

Comment: @sabithpocker Please find the added HTML content

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for answering my question. The answer may helps to someone.

By refreshing the drop-down using jquery dropkick() method, the drop-down gets refreshed and first value gets assigned.

```
$('#selectForMonth').dropkick('refresh');
```

Comment: Are you using a custom select plugin?